# Simple FParsec list example

Tags: f#, fparsec

I'm just getting started with FParsec and can't wrap my head around a simple list parser.
Given the input

`"{
  a;b;c
  d;
}"`

I want to get the result `['a';'b';'c';'d']`

If I do

```
let baseChars = ['0'..'9'] @ ['A'..'Z'] @ ['a'..'z'] @ ['_'; '-']
let chars : Parser<_> = anyOf baseChars
let nameChars : Parser<_> = anyOf (baseChars @ ['.'])                

let semiColonList p : Parser<_> = sepBy p (pstring ";")
let pList p : Parser<_> = between (pstring "{") (pstring "}") (semiColonList p)

do  """{
    a;b;c;
    d;
}"""
    |> run (parse {
        let! data = pList (spaces >>. many1Chars nameChars)
        return data
    })
    |> printfn "%A"
```

I get a failure on the last } as it's trying to match that on the nameChars parser before closing the between parser.
This feels like there is a simple solution that I'm missing, especially since if I delete the last semi-colon after d all works as expected.
Any help appreciated.

[edit]
Thanks to Fyodor Soikin the following works:

```
    let semiColonList p = many (p .>> (pstring ";" >>. spaces))
    let pList p : Parser<_> = between (pstring "{") (pstring "}") (semiColonList p)
    """{
    a;b;c;
    d;
}"""
    |> run (parse {
        let! data = pList (spaces >>. many1Chars nameChars)
        return data
    })
    |> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: `sepBy` doesn't admit a trailing separator. Try `many` instead.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin not sure what you mean there. I can't do `many notSemiColon` as that will backtrack and then expect the closing } after the first match (a)

Comment: I mean make a parser that parses both the value and the semicolon together, and then run `many` of that parser.

Comment: `semiColonList p = many (p .>> pstring ";")`

Comment: ah, thanks for the clarification, If you pop it in an answer I'll mark it and give you the cred ;)

Comment: Fyodor Soikin is correct that `sepBy` doesn't allow a trailing separator. BUT there's also `sepEndBy` which allows an optional trailing separator. That might be better for your needs. See https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.sepEndBy for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sepBy` does not admit a trailing separator. A parser like `sepBy a b` is meant to parse input like `a b a b a`, but your input is like `a b a b a b` - there's an extra separator `b` at the end.

What you want to do instead is to parse multiple expressions that are like `a b` - that will give you your desired shape of the input.

In order to parse one such expression, use the sequencing operator `.>>`, and in order to parse multiple such pairs, use `many`:

```
semiColonList p = many (p .>> pstring ";")
```